# bash Shell - not exiting for if-elif conditions

Tags: bash

Bash shell not exiting - for below code - although I don't get any errors.
Please help me with exit mechanism

When I press CTRL+D i get the output correctly for appropriate conditions

```
#!/bin/bash

read un < $HOME/un.txt

sqlplus $un @report.sql > Package_migration_report.`date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"`.xls 

mail_to="xxxx"

count=$(grep -c "no rows selected" $HOME/Package_migration_report.`date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"`.xls) 

error=$(grep -c ERROR $HOME/Package_migration_report.`date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"`.xls)

if [ "$error" -gt 0 ]

then

    echo -e "Error occurred\n\nNOTE: In case of Schema/password change is done to HARP database, the private variables in the script needs modifications - SCM team Will take appropriate action" |mailx -s "Package Migration Report for `date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"` "  $mail_to

elif [ "$count" -gt 0 ]

then

    echo -e "Hi All\n\nNo Packages where migrated for `date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"` \n\n\nThanks & Regards \nSCM team \n\n\n" |mailx -s "Package Migration Report for `date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"` "  $mail_to

else

    cat mail_content_2 | mailx -s "Package Migration Report for `date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"` "  -a $HOME/Package_migration_report.`date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"`.xls $mail_to

fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Some command is reading from stdin. Rather than guessing at what it is, use `bash -x yourscript` to run the script with each command logged.

Comment: BTW, there's a significant set of bugs here (largely involving missing quoting) that http://shellcheck.net/ will automatically detect. While doing so is unlikely to fix your immediate problem, you should consider going through and solving what it finds.

Comment: Also, see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section, recommending `printf '%b\n' "string with escape sequences"` in place of `echo -e` (which bash actually violates POSIX to implement, and disables support for when the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are both enabled).

Comment: I would advise you look up here documents so your code is much cleaner and easy to follow.  You may also wish to check is report.sql is terminated correctly

Comment: Calculate `date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"` once (avoid problems at 23:59) amd insert a newline after each pipe `|`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with username / password for database - As it was wrong - the control did not return from SQL and was waiting to re-enter password .

To fix this I have used Below one time logon option (-l flag) (it will not re-prompt for pwd) if password is wrong it will exit sql immediately :)

```
sqlplus -l $un @report.sql> Package_migration_report.`date -d "1 day ago" +"%b_%d_%Y"`.xls
```

Comment: This isn't a solution likely to help anyone else with a problem involving `if` / `elif` conditions (which, given the title, is the set of folks likely to come through here and find it). You might consider doing a better job of isolating issues in the future (building a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have revealed that the `if` had nothing to do with the issue) -- and either editing the question to focus on the real problem that the answer solves (so it'll be helpful to other people), or deleting it outright.

Answer (score -1):

Try `set -e` to exit the script at any error, but its unclear what your problem is...

Comment: `set -e` is [considered harmful](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- and it won't do anything to solve a program blocking on stdin.